# Sequence and Series doubt

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose $x_n \to x$ in metric space $X$ and $y_n \to y$ in metric space $Y$. When can we say $(x_n,y_n) \to (x,y)$ ?

i.e. what product metric will make it happen ?

Comment: Can you please provide more context? Is this a homework question? In any case, many product metrics should work.

Answer (score 3):

Any metric compatible with the product topology on $X\times Y$ will work. Three of the simpler are

$$\begin{align*}
&d(\langle x_0,y_0\rangle,\langle x_1,y_1\rangle)=\max\{d_X(x_0,x_1),d_Y(y_0,y_1)\;,\\
&d(\langle x_0,y_0\rangle,\langle x_1,y_1\rangle)=d_X(x_0,x_1)+d_Y(y_0,y_1)\;,\text{ and}\\
&d(\langle x_0,y_0\rangle,\langle x_1,y_1\rangle)=\sqrt{\big(d_X(x_0,x_1)\big)^2+\big(d_Y(y_0,y_1)\big)^2}\;.
\end{align*}$$